# Laptop monitor backlight

Tags: hardware

I've had two laptops, one Sony and another Acer. Sony laptops backlight can be decreased quite a bit, however the Acer laptops backlight brightness is too much.

I was wondering where these values sit and if there is a possibility to lower the laptop screen backlight brightness any lower than their current settings.

I don't know if this question belongs here but I've asked around a bit in forums and usual answer is to simply decrease brightness using GPU software. Yet this does nothing to the actual backlights, which in the night are eye piercing.

Comment: do you have any experience or do you want to do reverse engineering? or you're just trying to lower the brightness?

Comment: No, my problem isn't with simply lowering brightness. I want to turn down the backlight close to dark. I've programmed in Java, C# and a little bit python but have no clue how to reverse engineer. I thought I'd modify the following source http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/236898/Screen-Brightness-Control-for-Laptops-and-Tablets to lower the backlight even further yet I found out laptops have preset for backlight. So i guess this falls under reverse engineering.

Comment: What model is your Acer laptop?

Comment: Acer Aspire 5750G

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about reverse engineering.

Comment: I don't know where else to ask. I ask in windows forums, they tell me turn down the brightness. I ask on reddit tech support they tell me the same or get f.lux. I figured only thing I can try to do is get to motherboard settings and add my own values to backlight levels but have no clue how to. If you think this is not relevant, go for it, close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official [Quick Guide for the Acer Aspire 5750G](http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Document/QuickStartGuide/QuickStartGuide_Acer_1.0_A_A.zip?acerid=634304197158565322&Step1=NOTEBOOK&Step2=ASPIRE&Step3=ASPIRE%205750G&OS=ALL&LC=en&BC=ACER&SC=PA_6), you can use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to turn the backlight completely off, and you can use <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>▷</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>◁</kbd> to increase or decrease the screen brightness, respectively:

[image: 5750G]

The Acer Aspire 5750G has an Intel HD Graphics 3000 integrated graphics processor. So if you need more fine-grained control over the brightness, use the Intel HD Graphics Control Panel ([latest drivers for your laptop](http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Driver/VGA/VGA_Intel_8.15.10.2342_W7x86W7x64_A.zip?acerid=634761931954606771&Step1=NOTEBOOK&Step2=ASPIRE&Step3=ASPIRE%205750G&OS=ALL&LC=en&BC=ACER&SC=PA_6)) to manually adjust the backlight brightness:

[image: Intel HD Graphics Control Panel]

Comment: I already know this but the backlight brightness is too high even at lowest for night viewing.

Comment: I've updated the answer above after some Googling for you.

Comment: Thanks, i've tried that too. It does not help the backlight. Even completely black shines very brightly in the night. This is because of the backlight. I do not have the lower settings that are shown in the picture. I have latest intel drivers

Comment: If I were you, I'd contact customer support at Acer. There's no reason to believe that reverse engineering the drivers will allow you to lower the brightness any more than what's described above.

Comment: Also, in the future, it would help if you explained in your original question what you've already tried.

Comment: I guess I'll give up. Thanks a lot for your time and help. I'll accept this as an answer and hopefully get it closed.